# How to Make the Specific Block Expired once the validity Period of particular Block is Crossed in Go Language?

Tags: go

```
mins, _ := time.ParseDuration(fmt.Sprintf("%dmins", v.SalePeriod))
            local, _ := time.LoadLocation("Local")
            t, _ := time.ParseInLocation("2006-01-02 15:04:05", v.CreateTime, local)
            vTime := t.Add(time.Minute * mins)
```

t.Add(time.Minute * mins) is not working and the updated time is not getting updated

I Tried to Perform this operation : vTime := t.Add(time.Minute * mins)

```
// But the Piece of Block is not getting Expired
if time.Now().Local().After(vTime) {
                //Change status to expired
                var bodyBytes [][]byte   
                bodyBytes = append(bodyBytes, []byte(v.ObjectOfSale))
                bodyBytes = append(bodyBytes, []byte(v.Seller))
                bodyBytes = append(bodyBytes, []byte(v.Buyer))
                bodyBytes = append(bodyBytes, []byte("expired"))
                //call smart contract
                resp, err := bc.ChannelExecute("updateSelling", bodyBytes)
                if err != nil {
                    return
                }
                var data map[string]interface{}
                if err = json.Unmarshal(bytes.NewBuffer(resp.Payload).Bytes(), &data); err != nil {
                    return
                }
                fmt.Println(data)
            }
```

Comment: `mins` is already a duration in minutes (assuming you fix the format to "%dm"; I'd suggest the simpler `mins := time.Duration(v.SalePeriod) * time.Minute`, though). Multiplying that by time.Minute again makes it far longer than you intend.

Answer (score 1):

The function `time.ParseDuration` expects a string of format `?m` where `?` stands for a number.

You need to change `%dmins` to `%dm` in your format string to get a program working.

Links:

- `time.ParseDuration` doc: https://pkg.go.dev/time#ParseDuration
- Example solution on *go playground*: https://go.dev/play/p/DoChgPHMgN-

---

**Edit**

As @Peter noted, you also have redundant multiplication on `time.Minute`